# Bootstrap item order in multi-column item group

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to change the order of buttons in a Bootstrap list-group. I currently have the following layout (row first).

[image]

I'm trying to achieve a column first layout, like so.

[image]

I'm currently re-sorting the list to make this happen, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant approach to solve the problem.

https://www.bootply.com/pFSlgefurQ

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's much more elegant but you could always add this to your css:

```
.list-group {
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;

    -webkit-column-gap: 0; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-gap: 0; /* Firefox */
    column-gap: 0;
}
```

then make each Bootstrap column col-md-12 like so:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <button class="btn col-md-12">Row1</button>
    <button class="btn col-md-12">Row2</button>
    <button class="btn col-md-12">Row3</button>
    <button class="btn col-md-12">Row4</button>
    <button class="btn col-md-12">Row5</button>
    <button class="btn col-md-12">Row6</button>
</ul>
```

I get the same result. [See here on bootply](https://www.bootply.com/JVEgDlPAwb).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The solution seems to produce a strange layout when the number of buttons is not exactly divisible by the number of columns. See : https://www.bootply.com/UEC17uAIpe

Comment: Damn you're right, sorry about that, I find that column-count does indeed often make things messy.